# How to save screen configuration?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, display

I have a RPi 4 with 2 monitors running the latest version of Rasbian. For a few months, upon startup, the monitors have been mirrored where I would like them to act as one larger combined screen. I have altered the positions in the screen configuration tool but it resets every time the computer boots. Is there a command I can have run on startup or else a file I can alter to make sure they are positioned correctly on startup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found an answer..

If you create a .desktop file that executes the following code

```
    arandr --position <coordinates here>
```

and place that file in /home/pi/.config/autostart then upon boot it will correctly orient the screens at startup